# program hangs when calling ros::topic::waitForMessage

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will like to grab the data form a ros topic once and was using ros::topic::waitForMessage. However after calling the function, the program seem to freeze at that point.

Following is the code

```
int  main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 ros::init(argc, argv, "edgar_action");
     
     while(ros::ok())
     {   
       boost::shared_ptr<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryFeedback const> feedback;
       feedback = ros::topic::waitForMessage<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryFeedback>("/right_arm_controller/state",ros::Duration(5.0));
      if(feedback.use_count()==0)
       {
        ROS_WARN("Timeout getting '/right_arm_controller/state' message ");
        return 0;
       }
       else
       {
             ROS_INFO("Received  '/right_arm_controller/state' message ");
        }
       ros::spin();
     }
 return 0;
}
```

What might be causing this problem?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218829/program-hangs-when-calling-ros::topic::waitformessage/) by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found the issues. Silly me forgot to create a node handler. Creating a node handler before the while loop fixes the problem

---

Originally posted by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) with karma: 93 on 2015-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0